# How to find repeating matching values in two Data Frame columns in Python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I'm trying to write a script that will check if manager numbers match with employee number. It will continue down the column until all numbers are checked. 
When finished it will print a list of how many matched or didn't match.

```
[In:]
import pandas as pd

#reading in csv file to Data Frame
employeeData = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/EmployeeList.csv")

#creatig a Data Frame
dataF = pd.DataFrame(employeeData);

#empty list where instances of T/F will be stored
booleans = [];

#256 manager numbers + 1896 empty rows
managers = pd.Series(employeeData['Manager ID Number']

 #Edit Forgot to include this line
condition = managers.equals(merge['Employee ID'])

 #check each row of employee data. 2153 rows of Employee Numbers
 for index, row in employeeData.iterrows():
    #Check every single Manager number for a match
    for index, row in managers.iteritems():
         if condition:
         booleans.append(True)
         print("Something matched!")

         else:
         print("Didn't match!"
         booleans.append(False)
#A length of all booleans is printed. 
print(len(booleans))


[Out:] Actual 
"Didn't match!" x 2153 times. (number of employees in list)

[Out:] Desired: 
"Something matched!"
"Didn't match!"
"Something matched!"
"Something matched!"
"Didn't match!"
"Something matched!".... to line 2153
```

My problem is it seems the index count won't move down. It will only output that it didn't match with the first number hundreds of times. I want to move the row position down so it all the employee numbers are checked against the Manager list. Some managers have more employee's that others so I have to check every single one!(256) I'm embarrassed to say I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while. New to python so any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need to use [Pandas Merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df_emp_mng= pd.merge(df_Emp,df_Mang,left_on='EMP ID',right_on='Manager ID')
print (df_emp_mng)

print 'Number of managers in Employee' ,len(df_emp_mng)
print 'Number of managers not in Employee' ,len(df_Emp)-len(df_emp_mng)
```

input - Emplyee Data

```
   EMP ID name  MID
0     123   E3    1
1     124   E1    1
2     125   E2    2
3       4   X4    5
```

Input - Manager Data

```
   Manager ID Manager name Dep
0           1           X1   C
1           2           X2   D
2           3           X3   E
3           4           X4   F
4           5           X5   F
```

Output

```
   EMP ID name  MID  Manager ID Manager name Dep
0       4   X4    5           4           X4   F

Number of managers in Employee 1

Number of managers not in Employee 3
```